# How can I view the memory size of modules used by Apache?

Tags: apache

Ever since I started using my own Apache module on my server, I noticed that each Apache process size now went up from 30-50 MB to 60-70 MB+

I'm not sure if it is my module that is causing it, or if it's some random PHP code someone used that is eating up memory.

What I want to know is if there's a way that I can list the modules Apache has loaded along with the memory consumption for each.

I did try `httpd -M` but all I get is a list of loaded modules along with an indication as to whether they're static or dynamic.